# Array of TVarRec

Tags: c++, arrays, delphi, wrapper

I want use an array of struct, like array of TVarRec in delphi. My code is:

```
int doProduct(TVarRec Handle[])
{
    cout<<Handle[0].VInteger<<endl;
    cout<<Handle[1].VInteger<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(Handle); 
    return 0;
}
```

So delphi give me an array of `TVarRec`, my subject is treat arrays delphi in c++, when I use simple data it works, but when I try to use complex data likeTVarRec it possible only recognize  the first element of array (`Handle[0].VInteger<<endl;`) and the other are equal 0.

The Delphi code is a Console Application that consumes a C++ Dll. Well Delphi will charge my C++ Dll and use.

```
program Tx_ProduitCPP;

//To select a mode de compilation
{$IFDEF FPC}
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$modeswitch objectivec1}
{$ENDIF}

uses
  FastSharemem,
  Windows,
  U_Small_Lib in 'U_Small_Lib.pas',
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TArr_VarRec=array of TVarRec;
  TdoProduct = function (AArr_Parameters:array of const):integer;cdecl;
  TLibHandle = System.THandle;

var
  ldoProduct:TdoProduct;
  lHandle:TLibHandle;
  lVarRecInput: TArr_VarRec;
  lVarRecOutput:TArr_VarRec;
  x:integer;
  test_int: array  of integer;
const
  NilHandle = TLibHandle(0);

begin
  //CALL A DLL C++
  lHandle := LoadLibrary('C:\Users\preparateur\Desktop\Delphi_and_CPP_Tests\Test_fin\dlls\test.dll');

  // VERIFIES IF IT EXISTS
  if lHandle <> NilHandle then
  begin
    @ldoProduct := Get_Dll_Function_Adress(lHandle, 'doProduct');
    if @ldoProduct <> nil then
    begin
      Setlength(lVarRecInput,10);
      lVarRecInput[0].VInteger:= 15;
      lVarRecInput[1].VInteger:= 10;

      //CALL THE FUNCTION DOPRODUCT
      ldoProduct(lVarRecInput);
      writeln(#13#10,'There are: ',sizeof(PChar),' parameters');
    end;
  end;
  sleep(1000);
end.
```

I made a c++ struct similar a TVarRec,

```
struct TVarRec 
{
  int           VInteger;
  unsigned      VType;
  bool          VBoolean;
  char          VChar;
  long double*  VExtended;
  string *      VString;
  void*         VPointer;
  char*         VPChar;
  void*         VObject;
  void*         VClass;
  wchar_t       VWideChar;
  LPWSTR        VPWideChar;
  void*         VAnsiString;
  void*         VCurrency;
  void*         VVariant;
  void*         VInterface;
  void*         VWideString;
  uint64_t*     VInt64;
  void*         VUnicodeString;
};
```

Comment: What we are missing is the call to `doProduct`. Were you to show a complete program then we'd have more chance of understanding.

Comment: Agreed, this is not clear at all.  Are you trying to translate c++ code to delphi?  Are you trying to consume a library written in delphi in a c++ application?  Where is your Delphi code (is there any)?  You need to [edit] your question to show us the code that is not working as expected.

Comment: I have a delphi console applicattion, it'll consome a library written in C++, I'll show you my Delphi code, this must be more clear.

Comment: C++ doesn't recognize                                  **cout<<Handle[1].VInteger<<endl; **

Comment: You really cannot hope for this to work. Passing non-interop types like that. A delphi open array is not valid for interop. Use a SafeArray, for instance.

Comment: I understand your answer, but I made a similar struct in C++ like TVarRec.                          
Well only a TVarRec works, I can use all of elements of TVarRec, therefore if I use an array of TVarRec my Dll c++ recognize the first element of array.   cout<<Handle[0].VInteger<<endl; it works, the answer is 15.   cout<<Handle[1].VInteger<<endl; doesn't works the answer is 0, but Handle[1].VInteger should be equal 10.  If you want, I can edit my question

Comment: Er... Your C++ struct is not like `TVarRec` at all.

Comment: Why not? interger in C++ is a int, there's no Variant in C++, I put void *. My problem isn't the C++ struct, my problem is work with array of TVarRec. One siple TVarRec works, you can test it, it work as well.

Comment: C++ does have a VARIANT. Open arrays are not valid for interop. Just use a SAFEARRAY. This is what it was invented for.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try a Safearray, after I'll show you the result.